# How to access "types" dynamically with java?

Tags: java, android

I don't know what types.DocumentType is, but I'm doing an integration of an sdk and I created a cordova plugin. the import from the sdk is like this:

```
import exemple.types.DocumentType;

example.open(DocumentType.RG_FRENTE, myListener);
```

Can I somehow pass RG_FRENTE dynamically as it is done in javascript?

Something like:

```
example.open(DocumentType[my_parameter], myListener);
```

Comment: Not without using reflection. You'll probably want to use an explicit mapping for dynamic lookups, like a `Map<String, DocumentType>`.

Comment: With reflection. https://javahowtodoit.wordpress.com/2014/09/12/how-to-get-and-set-private-static-final-field-using-java-reflection/

Comment: @shmosel can you give me an example ? I really noob in java

Comment: Not without more context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution is only if DocumentType is enum class like below.

```
enum DocumentType {
    RG_FRENTE,
    RG_ETNERF;
}
```

You can directly get by the `valueOf` method like below.

```
DocumentType docType = DocumentType.valueOf("RG_ETNERF");
```

Or like this,  if you have it in variable.

```
String type = "RG_ETNERF";
DocumentType docType = DocumentType.valueOf(type);
```

Answer (score 0):

What @shmosel said is to define somewhere in your code a Map like:

```
Map<String,Integer> documentTypes = new HashMap<>() {{
                put("RG_FRENTE",DocumentType.RG_FRENTE);
                put("RG_ETNERF",DocumentType.RG_ETNERF);
        }};
```

(I assume here DocumentType.RG_FRENTE is an int (can be `Object`), as you don't tell us the type)

Later, you can access the values dynamically like

```
String my_parameter = "RG_FRENTE";
// ...
example.open(documentTypes.get(my_parameter), myListener);
```

If you like, you can create `documentTypes` by reflection, but always is better to avoid reflection in code.